# sum function not working when passed a vector variable

Tags: r, sum

```
x1 = c(2.5,3.5,4,5.78,0,4,78.9)
z1 <- sum(x[1],x[4])

x2 = c(2.5,3.5,4,5.78,0,4,78.9)
z2 <- sum(x)
```

when I run x1 and z1 I get correct output but when I run x2 and z2 I'm getting the following error

> "Error in sum(x) : argument "b" is missing, with no default"

`sum(x)` should also a valid way of using the sum right?

Comment: Do you create a `sum()` function by yourself? The sum function in the `base` package doesn't have an argument named `"b"`.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error you have shown. Please try it again on a fresh session.

Answer (score -2):

Keerthana

instead of writing `z2<-sum(x)` write `z2<-sum(x)`. This happens, when you are beginning.  Dont worry r is fun to learn.

Comment: My bad. Thanks a lot. -1

Keerthana

instead of writing z2<-sum(x) write z2<-sum(x2)